# How to switch to new gizmo in blender 2.8?

Tags: gizmo

I'm stuck with the 2.7 gizmo while running 2.8.  How do I switch to the  new gizmo in blender 2.8?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to use the 2.7 gizmo in 2.8, instead of the new gizmo?

Comment: I use blender 2.8,but the default gizmo is the left,,,i see other guy's 2.8 gizmo is the right....so i want know how to change the left to the right...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the top menu bar > *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Viewport* > *Display* > *3D Viewport Axis* > choose *Interactive Navigation*. It would make more sense to put this in the *3D View Viewport Gizmo* panel in my opinion.

[image]